# Iframe contents not visible in a chm file

Tags: html, iframe, chm

I am compiling one chm file with set of html files. In one html file i am using iframe tag and viewing text file throught 'src' attribute. I am able to see the contents of text file inside iframe when opening that HTML file in a browser. But when viewing that file in a chm file i don't see text file content. It is showing 'This page can’t be displayed' error in iframe.

This is the tag i'm using:

```
<iframe src="./mytextfile.txt" style="width: 100%; height: 300px;border:none"></iframe>
```

Is there anything to add to view that file. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see - your problem is reproducible (here on a German Windows10 machine).

[image]

You must ensure that the text file is either in the same directory as the project (.hhp) file or in a subdirectory of that directory.

You also have to add the *.txt file extension or filename to the [FILES] list in the .hhp file, as this ensures that the text file will be compiled into the .chm file. Best way is to do this by a text editor like shown below:

[image]

Save the *.hhp file and compile all content to your *.chm file.

[image]

Done!

BTW - here are some hints to another problem may be targeted:

Microsoft introduced some security restrictions many years ago that disable functionality in HTML Help files that are accessed over a network, so what you're seeing is almost certainly by design. There are two possible solutions: move the help file to your local drive, or implement some changes in the Windows registry so that you can view the contents of remote help files.

Microsoft's summary of the problem: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896054

You may try following workaround that lets you explicitly 'unblock' a CHM help file coming from a network drive or internet download. To do this:

- Open Windows Explorer
- Find your CHM file
- Right click and select Propertie
- Click the Unblock button on the General tab

For information on how to make the registry changes, see this page:
http://www.grainge.org/pages/authoring/chm_mspatch/896358.htm

Or more straightforwardly, use the free HHReg utility available from the page below to make the required changes.
http://www.ec-software.com/products_hhreg.html

Comment: Thank you, it's working after adding text file name to the FILES list in hhp file